# What is a canonical embedding?

Tags: functional-analysis

I‘m taking a course in functional analysis and have to show that $ L^1(\mathbb R) \subsetneq (L^\infty(\mathbb R))^* $ "in the sense of canonical embedding". What does this mean exactly? Unfortunately, "canonical embedding" is no term we defined in the lecture so I assume it is some "common term".

I think I have to show that there is a function

$$ \iota: L^1(\mathbb R) \to (L^\infty(\mathbb R))^* $$

such that $ \iota(L^1(\mathbb R)) \subsetneq (L^\infty(\mathbb R))^* $. But  just any function is probably not enough and $\iota$ has to satisfy some more properties. For example, i think injectivity would make sense.

Can somebody tell me what one means with a "canonical embedding"? Is it just a topological embedding, i.e. a homeomorphism onto its image as it is mentioned at Wikipedia?

Comment: A canonical embedding is an embedding that is understood from the context (that has been previously agreed upon to be canon). So here i would understand this to be the map that associates to an $L^1$ function an element in $(L^\infty)^*$ by integration against that function. So you need to show that this specific map is not surjective.

Comment: @jd27 But is just a map enough? Then choose $\iota$ as the constant null function and we’re done. This can’t be the intended solution.

Comment: i wrote "specific" map, how do you get the idea that this is about any map? See the answer from Trevor Gunn for the specific map i mean.

Comment: Due to Hölder's inequality, there's a natural (i.e. *canonical*) way to begin with $g \in L^q(\mathbb{R})$ and produce a functional $\kappa_p(g) \in (L^p(\mathbb{R}))^*$ via integration: 
$$
\kappa_p(g)(f) = \int_{\mathbb{R}} f(x)g(x) \, dx
$$ 
for any $f \in L^p(\mathbb{R})$. This holds whenever $\frac1p + \frac1q = 1$, including the case $(p, q) = (\infty, 1)$.

Comment: Concerning the word "canonical" see https://mathoverflow.net/q/19644 and https://mathoverflow.net/q/353061.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"Canonical" means the map defined most directly by the definitions/properties. Meaning there's no choice of basis or any elements being permuted. Here, this map is defined by the pairing

\begin{align}
L^1(\mathbb{R}) \times L^\infty(\mathbb{R}) &\to \mathbb{R} \\
(f, g) &\mapsto \int_{\mathbb{R}} fg
\end{align}

Every element of $L^1$ gives a functional $f^* = (f, -)$ on $L^\infty$ and that's the map: $f \mapsto f^*$.

Comment: And embedding means what? Just inclusion?

Comment: @ATW Yes, an injective map

Comment: With sets, we speak of an injective map, but when the sets carry extra structure (hence are called *spaces*) then it's more common to speak of embedding as long as the injection respects this extra structure. In this case, $L^p(\mathbb{R})$ is a vector space, and the canonical dual map is linear, i.e. respects the vector space structure.